# How can I protection my FLV videos?

Tags: flash, video, flv, drm, copy-protection

I have some FLV videos was to play on web (play in a flash player, e.g. JWPlayer). 
How can I protect it? I do not want someone else to download these videos!
The videos was high secret! Only allow play on my website.

Comment: The only way to achieve what you want to is not to play the videos on the web. Especially, if they are "secret"

Comment: Did there alternative to solve?
I was used Microsoft DRM, But video need convert to WMV I want use Flash, because I can custom the Player UI.

Comment: Any solution would only make copying hard, not impossible. What is to stop someone from catpuring the onscreen video using a camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no 100percent protection... as long as your website streams the video to a endpoint it might save the video... and reupload it whereever he wants...

things you could do: build an encrypted data-transportation-layer, implement some challange-based authentification, obfuscate your code, and hope that no-one reverse-engineers your authentication-algo/key :)

Comment: There *are* workable DRM solutions out there. No need to build this stuff from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do will 100% protect your content. (other than not making it available)

The best security I suppose would be to create a new (and really weird) video format and write a player for that format to use in your pages.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use RTMP instead of HTTP download of the videos. Using RTMP, you are sure that the client never saves the file anytime on disk.

Check the Red5 project or Adobe FMS.

Comment: it's just a transfer protocol; the stream data still gets to the client machine.

Comment: The data gets to Flash plugin on the client and the plugin never writes to disk.